# FTPS put file on FTP SERVER Using Shell

Tags: linux, shell, upload, tls1.2, ftps

I need to upload files of a directory /home/test to my ftp server, in a specific folder. I will then schedule the script hourly via cron. Any examples?
I try most solutions but i'm not able to put file. 
This is my code

```
HOST=*****
USER=****
PASSWORD=****
PORT=990
FILE=test.txt
ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
cd /Test
put test.test
bye
EOF
```

Comment: Let us know what issue you faced with your code.

Comment: Do you have SSH access, better use rsync. It has the option to only upload updated files.

Comment: I'm not able to connect to server. I have this message: 530 Please log with USER and PASS first

Comment: No, server doesn't have SSH access

Comment: Have you considered other tools?  One possibility is `lftp` for example [see here](http://superuser.com/questions/623236/simple-command-to-connect-to-ftps-server-on-linux-command-line) which might help you out

Comment: I have this message: put: test.txt: Fatal error: certificate verification:Not trusted

Comment: Have you actually tried logging in and uploading a file in interactive mode? Does the error appear there too?

Comment: When i use interactive mode, i have this message :FEAT Negociation.

Comment: Despite the message, does uploading work when in interactive mode?

Comment: not yet.  I try anything without success. I just need to upload file using shell and FTPS protocole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Found solution: Just do

```js
lftp -u $USER,$PASSWORD ftps://$HOST:$PORT <<EOF
set ssl:verify-certificate no
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
put test.txt
exit
EOF
```

Thanks a lot for your ideas.